# How to modify the look of ggplot plots at global level in R notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, knitr

I'm trying to get to grips with R Notebook, and have found options that can be applied at the top to produce a standard look for charts when I output to Word.

For instance:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=4, fig.height=3,
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

I know how to chain commands such as theme_minimal() to a plot, or how to manually change the fill colour of a plot such as in:

```
library(Lahman)
Lahman::Batting %>% 
  head() %>% 
  select(playerID, AB) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = playerID, y = AB))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()
```

But is it possible to redefine the defaults at the top of a notebook so that charts have a particular colour scheme or theme?

Comment: After you load `ggplot2`, you can set a theme globally with `theme_set()`. For example, run `theme_set(theme_classic())`. ggplot has several built-in themes (to see them, run `?theme_grey`). Also check out the `ggthemes` package. You can also define your own themes or modify existing ones.

Comment: Thank you for that. I learn so much every day.

Comment: did you figure out how to set size globally? can you post an answer if so